# Remove the white gaps, or no data regions, from the histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

I want to plot Histogram plot. This is temperature. It will never be more than +- 150. But the real data has some bad values, may be inserted into the database by the datalogger when it fails to hear from the sensor in time. I want to plot histogram plot, so, I should know from it presence of any bad data and how much it is.

My code:

```
  # I did log on the y-scale. It did help me in finding the complete range and their percentage. This was good
  ax = sns.histplot(df,x='Temperature',stat='percent',bins=200)
  ax.set_yscale('log')
  plt.show()
```

[image]

I wanted to see the x-axis ticks completely. Mainly there is a large white gap between the -8000 and 0. I want to delete this space where there is no data. So, I did the log on x-scale. It did help in seeing the complete range positive values but it delete negative values.

```
  ax = sns.histplot(df,x='Temperature',stat='percent',bins=200)
  ax.set_yscale('log')
  ax.set_xscale('log')
  plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: A histogram, by definition, shows a continuous distribution on the axis. You can manually bin the date with pandas.cut, or use numpy to create the bins and counts, remove the empty bins, and then plot a standard barplot.

Comment: The question should continue a complete [mre] with **sample data** as formatted text.